# LUIS List entity

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I am using "list" entity. However, I do not achieve my expected result.

**Here is what I have for LUIS intent:**

- `getAnimal`

  - I want to get a cat**[animal]**.

---

Here is what I have with LUIS entities:

**List Entities [animal]**

- `cat`: russian blue, persian cat, british shorthair
- `dog`: bulldog, german shepard, beagle
- `rabbit`: holland lop, american fuzzy lop, florida white

---

**Here is what I have with LUIS Phrase lists:**

Phrase lists [animal_phrase]

- `cat`, `russian blue`, `persian cat`, `british shorthair`, `dog`, `bulldog`, `german shepard`, `beagle`, etc

---

**Desired**:
When user enters "`I want to get a beagle`." It will be match with "`getAnimal`" intent.

**Actual**:
When user enters "`I want to get a beagle.`" It will be match with "`None`" intent.

Please help. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you force the entity to match the one as you want, I use LUIS last year and solve the problem that way. You can make a list of animal and use [animal] entity on it, it should match

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta, Sorry, do u mind explain with more details or giving an example? Currently, my [animal] entity consist of various words such as "dog", "cat" and their breeds. What do you mean by force the entity to match?

Comment: check this, it's called training https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3175

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta Do u mean training the bot by adding it to correct intent? eg adding utterance "I want a beagle" into the [animal] intent? If do so, wouldn't it adding utterance of the same format?

Comment: @Guesssme, I am not sure. I have not used from a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So using a phrase list is a good way to start, however you need to make sure you provide enough data for LUIS to be able to learn the intents as well as the entities *separate* from the phrase list. Most likely you need to **add more utterances**.

Additionally, if your end goal is to have LUIS recognize the `getAnimal` intent, I would do away with the list entity, and instead use a **simple entity** to take advantage of LUIS's machine learning, and do so in combination with a **phrase list** to boost the signal to what an animal may look like.

As the [documentation on phrase lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-feature) states,

> Features help LUIS recognize both intents and entities, but features
>   **are not intents or entities themselves**. Instead, features might
>   provide examples of related terms.

--Features, in machine learning, being a distinguishing trait or attribute of data that your system observes, and what you add to a group/class when using a phrase list

---

Start by

#### 1. Creating a **simple entity** called `Animal`

---

#### 2. Add more utterances to your `getAnimal` intent.

Following best practices outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-best-practices), you should include at **least 15 utterances per intent**. Make sure to **include plenty of examples of the `Animal` entity**.
3. Be mindful to include **variation** in your utterances that are valuable to LUIS's learning (different word order, tense, grammatical correctness, length of utterance and entities themselves). Highly recommend reading this [**StackOverflow answer I wrote on how to build your app properly get accurate entity detection**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650025/luis-intent-not-returning-the-entire-value-of-the-entity-with-space) if you want more elaboration.

[image]
above blue highlighted words are tokens labeled to the simple `Animal` entity

---

#### 3. Use a **phrase list**.

Be sure to include values that are not just 1 word long, but **2, 3, and 4 words long in length**, as different animal names may possibly be that long in length (e.g. `cavalier king charles spaniel`, `irish setter`, `english springer spaniel`, etc.) I also included 40 animal breed names. Don't be shy about adding Related Values suggested to you into your phrase list.

[image]

---

#### After **training** your app to update it with your changes, prosper!

Below "`I want a beagle`" reaches the proper intent. LUIS will even be able to detect animals that were not entered in the app in entity extraction.

[image]