# Couldn't find the entities being created in the Dispatch Model in Bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I followed this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs
to create the dispatch model.
It got successfully created. But when I tested it, it didn't add the entities to the dispatch model. I even checked the luis created and the html file which was generated.
Now my question is:
1. Do we need to add the .json and .tsv files to the same folder where we will be creating the dispatch files?
2. Does this folder needs to be created inside the bot source code folder?

What could be the reason of entities not being identified?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [README](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/Dispatch/readme.md) provided by Microsoft,

## Creating your dispatch model

To create, train and publish your new dispatch model:

```
dispatch create [options] 
dispatch create --bot c:\src\bot\testbot.bot --secret <your_bot_file_secret>
```

Options:

`-b, --bot` (optional) Path to .bot file or bot services json file

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. For a useful answer explain why this is an answer to the two questions.

Comment: I couldn't get your answer @Alicia. Could you please elaborate it further.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Dispatch CLI not passing Entities from Luis App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930061/dispatch-cli-not-passing-entities-from-luis-app).

TL;DR **the entities that you added to the children services of your parent dispatch model show up in the `connectedServiceResult` section of the response from dispatch.** See post linked above for more details

Comment: Sure I'll check the mentioned link.