# LUIS trying to get pattern matching for club location

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I have a LUIS app where I'm trying to get it to recognize
`{Organization Name }` of `{Location}`.

Example:

- Book club of Illinois
- Book club of Chicago
- Book club of Orlando,
  Florida

I tried creating a composite entity, where the child was a `GeographyV2` (I added that as a prebuilt entity).  Upon trying to do this, the training breaks.  I had to remove the composite entity.

The club part will always contain the same text, like "Book club of `{location}`".

Comment: @Zeryth thanks for the edit, I was hoping you could also answer the qeustion?

Comment: You might try pattern entities, but I've found they can be quite tempremental. For example you could set it up as `{organizationNamePatternEntity}` of `{Location}`, but if you're not specific enough, you could end up with something like `I'm looking for the book club` as the organization name if someone types "I'm looking for the book club of Illinois".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be rooted in that you haven't given enough data for `OrganizationName` entity to even be detected on its own, so detecting it in a composite entity should fail too.

---

**Create an intent with enough utterances with entities that can stand on their own**

- Below I've quickly just made a `JoinClub` intent, and provided at least 15 utterances for the intent.
- Turned on prebuilt `geographyV2` entity
- Created a simple entity, `Organization` to gather name of the organization

[image] 
[image]

Then after training, you can see in the Test panel that LUIS's machine-learning was able to pick up the `Organization` entity:
[image]

---

**Bundle related entities together with a composite entity**

- I created a `Club` entity with 2 children: `Organization` and `geographyV2`

Make sure to label the utterances in the intent with the new composite entity.

Upon testing, again we prosper! The entities are properly grouped as the `Club` composite entity, while the children are also correctly extracted as well:
[image]

---

For additional information about how properly build your LUIS apps so that entities properly extract, see my previous two responses on StackOverflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52656368/9781122
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52769408/9781122

Comment: Thank you.  I got it to work using a composite entity.  I sort of stumbled on it, then I saw this.   I think I'm doing it the same way as you mentioned.  Seems to be working ok.    Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, as an update to this, it is very difficult to go to intents in the portal and try to pick out known entities and mark them as a composite.  This is both from the intents and patterns page. The portal is buggy, cursor and selections jump around.  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I managed to get it one time with super ninja click accuracy and luck

Comment: Not sure what instruction to give, other than what is already listed in [documentation](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-language-understanding-luis/filters/my_feedback) with how to assign composite entities in the LUIS portal. You could explain what feature you would like or what is troubling you in [LUIS's uservoice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-composite-entity#create-composite-entity-from-example-utterances) forum, where the community can help prioritize new features

Comment: I understand.  Thank you for the response.  It is difficult to explain here without a video.  I will try the other route