# How can you use LUIS Phrase Lists to boost Pattern recognition?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

This is a question that was originally asked as a comment to another question ([LUIS adding patterns to intents is not taking any effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334572/luis-adding-patterns-to-intents-is-not-taking-any-effect/61353147?noredirect=1#comment108565454_61353147)) related to LUIS Patterns. Migrating it to its own post to make the information more readily searchable to the community.

---

"How do you get [LUIS] phrase list to work properly? I have never been able to get it to recognize the values in the actual entity. I've always had to create a list entity and add synonyms to the normalized values."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**

- Patterns in LUIS depend first on being able to detect an entity in order to match a pattern properly.
- Use a **simple entity** and **phrase list** to boost detection of that simple entity.

---

Phrase lists are used to "boost" the signal of another entity, but relies on the entity that you are trying to boost a signal for to have enough data to identify it in at least some cases.

So let's say you properly have a **simple `Apple` entity** defined, and LUIS detects values properly like `Golden Delicious` , `Granny Smith`, `Cosmic`, etc. It could maybe even properly detect a brand new (made-up) apple crop, `Flamingo`, even if you did not explicitly label `Flamingo` value as the `Apple` entity in an utterance.

LUIS uses machine learning based off the context of utterances to identify, "Oh yeah, normally an `Apple` entity can occur here, so `Flamingo` must be an `Apple`." `Flamingo` is also an English word, so LUIS has "background knowledge" of this word already (for example, could know based off of the English language that it's a noun).

But what if a university created a new apple crop name that did not exist in English--like `Jirio`, for example. LUIS has no background knowledge of that word, as it did with `Flamingo`. So you could create a **phrase list** to help identify `Jirio` properly as an `Apple`.

I can create a new `Apples` phrase list, and include LOTS values like `Golden Delicious`, `Granny Smith`, `Jirio`, etc. And when LUIS looks: "I don't know what `Jirio` is, but I do know what a `Golden Delicious` is. A `Jirio` looks like it's the same thing as a `Golden Delicious` according to the `Apples` phrase list, and thus is more likely to label `Jirio` as an `Apple` entity.

---

**Related StackOverflow Posts that are also helpful (with screen shots!)**:

- [How to Improve Entity Detection in your LUIS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650025/luis-intent-not-returning-the-entire-value-of-the-entity-with-space/52656368#52656368)
- [How to build a Phrase List to properly boost entity detection in your LUIS App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52769408/9781122)
- [Phrase Lists in Dispatch (Cell Phone Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012604/9781122)

Comment: I just want to emphasize here that it appears phrase lists only work with `Simple` entities. My issue was that I was always trying this with `List` entities. I have tested and verified that I cannot get the same behavior to work with Lists.